# Android time selection in a unique way

Tags: android, android-layout, time-select

(I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0)

How can I make this kind of time selection in my app's layout?
Is it a ready made component? How is it called?
I'm talking about the circular part where the user can select how many minutes/hours until...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can not confirm if it is a custom part of the mobile operating system, but it looks very much like a custom built app. Jquery Knob is the closest I have seen to something like this, but would require some heavy customization to begin to resemble that.

http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/ <-- Home Page
https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob <-- Git Hub Repository

Nice, downward compatible, touchable, jQuery dial

Comment: Not sure I understood how to implement this in an Android app's layout. The image is from an app that uses this knob/dialer for itself and I was wondering if I can achieve something similar to that

Comment: You will need to specify what platform you are using for anybody to even commence to answer your questions further. Please list everything relating to how you are building your app etc.

Comment: unfortunately Jquery Knob is not suitable for your platform. I have not worked on Android Studio so can not comment on that platform.